# Appendix after references not in toc and figure label missing

Tags: latex

I am trying to set up my Appendix for my master's thesis which includes basically only figures. These will be referenced at the end of the "List of figures". 
My intention is to have figures called "Fig. A.1", "Fig. A.2" etc. 
Also, the appendix should be part of the table of contents.

This works fine, as long as it appears before the bibliography.
However, the appendix should appear afterwards, and as soon as I move it there, the Figures are only called "Fig. .1" and it disappears from the TOC. (Note that the figures still show up in the list of figures, however with the wrong names).

How can I reach the same result while having the Appendix BELOW the references?

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\renewcommand{\figurename}{Fig.}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\fancyhead[EC]{\large REFERENCE LIST}% page header is always ``Reference List''
\fancyhead[OC]{\large REFERENCE LIST}% 

\section* {Reference List} %removes the section from sections numbers and TOC
\addcontentsline {toc}{section}{Reference List} %adds the section to TOC
\bibliographystyle{THESIS2} %my custom bibliography style
\renewcommand{\section}[2]{} %removes superfluous ``References'' title
\bibliography{Literatur} %calls my .bib file

\newpage

\fancyhead[EC]{\large APPENDIX}
\fancyhead[OC]{\large APPENDIX}


\addcontentsline {toc}{section}{Appendix}
\appendix

\section{Appendix}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am still struggling with that. anybody can help?